# Can you change the update interval for the hardware-monitor applet?

Tags: applet, monitoring

I want to change the update interval of the hardware-monitor applet. There's no setting for it in preferences...

Answer (score 1):

The hardware monitor applet gets its data from lm-sensors, the data is taken raw from the system and lm-sensors does not limit the amount of times it collects this information so unless you are good at programming and want to help the hardware monitor team add the function your best bet at the moment would be to create a script to switch on and off the lm-sensors service at regular intervals to dictate how often the data is sent to the applet.

Hope this helps.